# FastApi can't redirect after sending request with token

Tags: javascript, python, jwt, fastapi

function in client javascript when button is pressed:

```
function request_dashboard() {
    const apiUrl = 'dashboard';

    // Replace 'YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN' with your actual Bearer token.
    const bearerToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

    // Create headers object with Authorization header containing the Bearer token.
    const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
    };

    // Make the GET request using the fetch API.
    fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    }).then(response => {
        window.location.href = '/dashboard';
    })
}
```

FastApi Route:

```
@router.get("/")
def dashboard_view(request: Request, user: UserRead = Depends(auth.get_current_user)):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("dashboard.html", {"request": request})
```

logs when clicking button:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59992 - "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59992 - "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59992 - "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect    
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59992 - "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 401 Unauthorized
```

So when using fetch, everything works, my token is authenticated and the route function is called, but when doing window.location.href = '/dashboard', anoter api call is made without authorization header and receive 401 error.
How to fix?

Comment: You've registered `/dashboard/`, but are calling `/dashboard`. FastAPI then issues a 307 redirect to `/dashboard/`, which your client (javascript) follows, but doesn't attach the Authorization header to. Either use `/dashboard/` in your request or register `@app.get('')` instead of `@app.get('/')`.

Comment: Doing that removed the 307 redirect response, yet the problem persists: INFO:  "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:  "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 401 Unauthorized
The first get is from the fetch with bearer, the secong from setting window href in js script

Comment: Ok so I may have found a workaround by not using Oauth2_scheme, and by sending the token encoded in the url

Comment: Please tell me how you got it. Same issue here